# Arithmetic Operations in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want your help. I am doing my University Assignment. I am working on IndexedDB. I want to-do some addition, subtraction with data that is coming from my indexedDB as an object. I am retrieving values from IndexedDB and save that for future use for applying arithmetic operations.

When i sum the data then it concatenate numbers.

> For Example:
>
> total += price[index].name;
>   //in price array there is data like 100,50,20
>   my output should be sum of these values. but i am getting the output like this "1005020"

I don't know how to add this data. here is my code.

```js
function GetData(){
 var output = document.getElementById("printOutput");
     var product=[];
     var price=[];
     var person=[];
     var index=0;
     var total = 0;
                    var transaction = db.transaction("accounts", IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("accounts");
 
                    var request = objectStore.openCursor();
                    request.onsuccess = function(evt) {  
                    
     var cursor = evt.target.result;  
                        
                            if(cursor)
       {
        product.push({name: cursor.value.pType});
        price.push({name: cursor.value.pPrice});
        person.push({name: cursor.value.personID});
        cursor.continue();
       }
                    while(product.length!=index)
     {
      if(person[index].name==1){
      var element = document.createElement("p");
      element.textContent = product[index].name+"\t"+price[index].name;
      output.appendChild(element);
      total = total + price[index].name;
      }
      index++;
     }
     var sum = document.createElement("p");
     sum.textContent = "Total Amount = " + total;
     output.appendChild(sum);     
 
                    };}
```

Comment: Typically data is retrieved from IDB in form of String object, so your "+" operator is concatenating instead of adding. So, first convert your Strings into number and then perform addition. For conversion - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+convert+string+to+number&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=240aVqXGLpCWuATrl5SoCw. This will solve your problem, but please let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It Worked!!

Comment: One more thing. Is there any tool that will debug my code. I want to debug my code so that i can verify that which line of code exactly is not working. I am working on NotePad++

Comment: You can debug JS in browser .. Check this - https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+developer+tools+debug+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 .. This is example of Chrome, similarly all browsers have developers tools for these kind of things ..

Comment: I have posted it as answer, could you please accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

For folks visiting hence forth, solved through comments and below is solution:

> Typically data is retrieved from IDB in form of String object, so your
>   "+" operator is concatenating instead of adding. So, first convert
>   your Strings into number and then perform addition. For conversion
>   please refer [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript%20convert%20string%20to%20number&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=240aVqXGLpCWuATrl5SoCw)

Comment: IDB can store any value that can be cloned via https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data - it might better to suggest that numeric data be stored as numbers, rather than stored as strings and converted on each retrieval. But if it's too late and the data is already stored as strings, the answer is correct,